# Documentdb java SQL API- Query collection with space

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to query a collection which has space in the name. Due to a restriction I cannot use query with alias like `select * from c` I have to use collection name and also qualify fields with collection name in WHERE clause e.g. `select * from "collection with space" where "collection with space".field1 = <value1> AND "collection with space".field2 = <value2>`. I tried enclosing the collection name in single quotes, it did not work either.
Is a query with space in collection and field name complies to the SQL grammar?
I am using SQL java API 1.15.

Comment: Note that I marked this as a duplicate of a question asking how to query collections where the collection name has a hyphen. Same problem, same solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please use syntax: `c["some valve"]` which is mentioned in this [official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#EscapingReservedKeywords)

My sample document :

```
[
    {
        "id d": "3",
        "id": "***"
    }
]
```

Query sql:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c["id d"]='3'
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This isn't the question the OP is asking. It's about the collection name having a space, not a property name. And this has already been asked (and answered) - i marked the question as such.